# How can we talk about limit at infinity?

Tags: limits

Can we state such a limit like; $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.If we can , Doesn't this violate the definition of limit , which is the fact that x goes the c where c is a (Real)number ?

If x can goes infinity then it has some conclusions like ;

the function $f(x)=x^2$ cannot be continuos when $f(x)=\infty$,hence in the definition of the continuity says that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=f(\infty)=\infty$ ,which means LIMIT DOESN'T EXIST.

Comment: Can Ones who voted down explain why ?

Comment: No, it doesn't violate anything, unless you can point to some universal law that excludes the possibility of making all the definitions we like. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I'm not changing definition as I like ,I just quoted it from a textbook.

Comment: The textbook is allowed to make any definition. You are not allowed to arbitrarily interpret them: just take them for what they say.

Comment: You are mixing things up. $\infty$ is not a number. The limit you have should be give the meaning: when $x$ grows large, so does $f(x)$. Also, I'm guessing that the definition of continuity you have is for $c\in{\mathbb{R}}$. But as I said $\infty$ is not a number. Thus taking about $f(\infty)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @dav11 As far as I understand you are saying the the meaning of $x\to\infty$ is just x becomes bigger and bigger  but even if so , it doesn't solve any problem because f(x) again goes to $\infty$

Comment: @dav11 So if $f(\infty)$ doesn't make any sense , how can we talk about continuity of f(x) when it is equal to $\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the statement, which you haven't really written down, but I am guessing at, is probably, that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous on the real numbers. This is fine. For any $a$, you have that the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ of $f$ is $a^2$. Your trouble seems to be stemming from regarding $\infty$ as a real number. It isn't.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, a function is indeed "continuous" in the calculus textbook sense when the limit approaching some number equals the value at that number. But $\infty$ is not a number and doesn't figure into this notion of continuity. Also, it looks like your main problem is not limits at infinity, but limits that "equal" infinity, since there are many functions that tend towards some real number at $\infty$ like $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.

Comment: @Leth - Look at your textbook's *actual definition* of a limit at $\infty$; you'll see that *nothing in the definition assumes that there's any such thing as $f(\infty)$*.

Comment: The answer is easy: We don't.

Comment: While trying to answer the comments , I lost track .Can you sum up what you are saying ?

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused because there are "two different types" of  $\lim$. Namely, one type of limit is as $x$ goes to some number. Another type of limit is as $x$ goes to infinity (or negative infinity). Although people tend to say things like

> The limit of $f(x)=x^2$ as $x$ goes to infinity

This is really different from

> The limit of $f(x)=x^2$ as $x$ goes to 2

In fact, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ is defined differently from $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$. More specifically, $\lim_{x\to c}$ is about what happens when $x$ is close to $c$, while $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ is about what happens when $x$ gets larger and larger. Consult the defintions in your book, and this should be clear.

So to answer your question, you **can** state a limit such as $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$, just like you can do anything in math. This "limit", however, may not exist, in a sense that it is not a real number. For example, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2$ does not make sense as you said, because $\infty$ is not a real number. But that does not violate the definition. After all, definition does not guarantee that a limit exists!

To answer the continuous part of your question. Continuity is not about what happens when $x$ gets larger and larger, but instead it's about what happens when $x$ is close to a point, usually a real number.

Comment: Not to confuse the issue, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2$ does "make sense". It is an example of an infinite limit at infinity.